# New electronic cooktop

Tags: electrical, wiring

I recently purchased a new electric radiant cooktop.  In connecting the new cooktop we noticed that the junction box has 4 wires (a black, a red, a white and a bare ground wire) while the cooktop has 3 wires (a yellow/green earth wire, a blue nule wire and a brown live wire)  How should this new cooktop be connected

Comment: Model number and make - link to manual? Follow the manual/installation instructions. There may well be a diagram right on the device. This is not a good place for vague guesses, even if the likely vague guesses might be right.

Comment: Are you in the States and bought a European stovetop?  The States uses two 120 volt wires to get 240 volts.  Europe uses one wire for 220 volts.  The two systems don't play nice together without extra(sometimes expensive) help.

Comment: Some stuff is easy (built in a way that Euro/worldwide and US/Canada power can both work) others are not. And sometimes old "commonwealth" wire colors make us think someone is in US/Canada when they are not. So, [edit]ing details would help immensely.

Comment: Model #? Nameplate details? Sounds like a euro model. Which is fine voltage wise (use red black and green cap the white) but frequency could be an issue.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact -- doubt frequency is an issue for a cooktop, since there's nothing motorized there, just resistive elements (not bothered by mains frequency) and/or stuff with rectifier front ends (also largely not bothered by mains frequency)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I generally agree. But since this is a hard-wired device there really is an issue of whether it is appropriate for the location. If it says 50/60, no problem. If it says 50 Hz then I'd be concerned unless the manufacturer confirms that it is OK for 60 Hz.

Comment: What is a "nule" wire? a Neutral?  If so please edit your post to change that.   ....Next: the OP said "electric radiant cooktop", if it's just a smooth surface with typical electrical resistance elements, probably no problem. But if it's induction, they'd have to be sure it can work on 50 or 60 HZ depending upon their location and the specs of the cooktop.

Answer (score 3):

It's common for cooktops to not require neutral.

General in range/oven packages, what needs the neutral is the oven light, so that common incandescent 120V bulbs can be used. Neutral sits between the two 240V wires, giving 120V to either hot wire.  But cooktops don't have oven lights.

Being an induction cooktop doesn't make a difference here.

The unused neutral wire should be treated as it as if hot (it sometimes is), and capped off with a wire nut and that nut taped on. (because rarely have the correct size nut for capping *one* wire, so the tape is needed so the nut doesn't fall off.)